# Node Playwright - How to remove part of visible content by checking off checkbox?

Tags: node.js, playwright

In the html there is an input, that I need to check so that content is NOT being shown (Im doing that because otherwise I would need to scrape content with pagination).

```
<input type="checkbox" name="TRAFFIC" />
```

```
await page.locator('[name="TRAFFIC"]').check()
```

then:

```
await page.getByRole('section', { name: 'contentThatIwant'})
const html = await page.content();
await context.close();
await browser.close();
return html;
```

The html, however, still shows content that was suppose to be removed once the checkbox is checked. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's hard to help without the site.

Comment: https://www.bvg.de/de/verbindungen/stoerungsmeldungen with      await page.getByRole('section', { name: 'U-Bahn'})

Comment: Thanks. What result are you trying to get on the page?

Comment: i want to click the checkbox that says 'Verkehrsmeldungen' so disabling it (is is enabled by default) (accessing it like: await page.locator('[name="TRAFFIC"]').check()), then the page will no show results for 'Verkehrsmeldungen'